# Node editor grid lines disappeared

Tags: node-editor, interface

Does someone know why I have these dots instead of the normal grid? Did it change in an update?

[image]

Comment: it's the new Shader Editor background, I don't know if it can be changed...

Comment: Yeah, that threw me too - I thought it was an OpenGL error or something at first. It's the reason I'm still using 3.0 alpha for most things - I can't stand the "dots" - they make my eyes hurt.

Comment: At least custom group background is not green anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of this change:

https://developer.blender.org/rBe463d2c16f72e9

Background has been replaced and there is no way to change it back.